# Wait until all tasks finish in queue to return the value , using async library

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have used async library to do some tasks concurrently, using the queue, my problem is I update the result inside `drain`, but when I return the result at end of function, it's still have initial value. should I use promise and async/await again on the queue? this is my code :

```
result = false;
const q = async.queue((task, callback) => {
console.log('Uploading : ', task.src)
s3.upload({
  Bucket: outputBucket,
  Key: task.desc,
  Body: fs.createReadStream(task.src)
}, callback)
}, PARALLEL_TASK)

q.drain = function() {result= true;}

q.push(fileNamesReformat)

return result; // HERE It's still false!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the solution, in case if anyone need, I need to return :

```
return q.drain()
```

based on async documentation , drain is a callback that is called when the last item from the queue has returned from the worker

Answer (score 1):

http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#queue

```
// assign a callback
q.drain = function() {
  console.log('all items have been processed');
};
```

http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#QueueObject
drain   function  a callback that is called when the last item from the queue has returned from the worker.